# Setting an instance of an object to another one from inside, using this = new Foo()?

Tags: c++, arrays, copy, hashtable, this-pointer

I am working with a hash table and to rehash it, I am simply putting all the values into a new hash table, and then setting the executing instance to this new hash table.

I wasn't sure going into it if that was possible, so I just want to confirm if this is the case. I am trying:

```
Foo *new_foo = new Foo();
...
delete this;
this = new_foo;
```

I know the problem isn't the delete line, since it doesn't work even without that. This is the error: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.

Also, just as a side question, what's the best/standard way for copying allocated arrays? `*a = *b`? I'm new to C++, obviously, and it would be helpful to know, but not necessary.

Comment: As you say, `delete this` as such is not a problem. But after deleting the object, there is nothing left. You can't do **anything** with it - it just isn't there anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Program cannot modify `this` to point to a different object. `this` is a constant pointer ( i.e., `T* const` ).

```
this = new_foo; // incorrect.
```

**what's the best/standard way for copying allocated arrays?**

Using `*a = *b;` doesn't copy the entire array. You are just copying the value at first index of `b` to first index of `a`. Use `std::copy`, instead.

---

```
int a[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 } ;
int b[5] ;

// To copy element of a to b -

std::copy( a, a+5, b ) ; // you need to include <algorithm> header.
```

Comment: "Also `delete this` results an undefined behavior." -- nothing of the sort: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/freestore-mgmt.html#faq-16.15

Comment: @Jon - That always confuses me. What if there are statements that needed to executed by `this` after deleting it ? Does that behavior defined ?

Comment: The link I gave clearly states that doing such *is* undefined behavior. But the actual `delete this` is not undefined behavior under specific circumstances. There are (a few, corner) cases where you really do want to `delete this`, and it will work fine.

Comment: Contrary to common belief, `this` is *not* `const` (it's an rvalue, however).

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to `this`. Consider creating a static method that creates and returns the new instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is telling you what you need to know. The `this` keyword isn't an lvalue, and therefore you can't assign to it. Why can't you just do this?:

```
Foo *old_foo = ...
Foo *new_foo = new Foo();
delete old_foo;
old_foo = new_foo;
```

Or, if it's really a hash table, create an "empty" method that walks the elements and deletes them all rather than deleting itself.